# get ntlm token (www-authenticate - header)

Tags: c#, rest, authentication

Authenticating in C# against a webservice (REST) with Windows Login (NTLM) is easy to do (like below example) but is there any way to output the NTLM-token ("www-authenticate" header)?

```
using System;
using System.Net;

namespace ConsoleApp1
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            string URL_status = "http://localhost/status";

            CredentialCache myCache = new CredentialCache();
            myCache.Add(new Uri(URL_status), "NTLM", new NetworkCredential("username", "password", "domain"));

            WebClient WebClient = new WebClient();
            WebClient.Credentials = myCache;

            for (int i = 1; i <= 5; i++)
            {
                string Result = WebClient.DownloadString(new Uri(URL_status));
                Console.WriteLine("Try " + i.ToString() + ": " + Result);
            }

            Console.Write("Done");
            Console.ReadKey();
        }
    }


}
```

Comment: your code only shows you outputting the downloaded content, not the headers, what did you try?

Comment: of course i printed all headers to console, but i did not find any www-authenticate in request nor in response